# How to use the value from a MongoDB document to query itself?

Tags: mongodb

I have the following collection with this document structure:

```js
  {
    "_id": "64f10520de562a0007595b56",
    "location": {
      "type": "Point",
      "radius": 62.474601140938596,
      "coordinates": [
        -100.28823650799032,
        25.68087292245721
      ]
    }
  }
```

So i want to use the "radius" property value in the query, like this:

```js
db.collection.find({
  location: {
    $geoWithin: {
      $centerSphere: [
        [
          -103.83176,
          20.88196
        ],
        10 / "RADIUS_PROPERTY_VALUE" // -> 62.474601140938596
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

is there a way to achieve this?

[MONGODB PLAYGROUND SCENARIO](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cSS4wo2hwle)

Comment: I've never tried it, but does replacing `10 / "RADIUS_PROPERTY_VALUE"` with `{$divide: [ 10, "$location.radius"]}` work?

Comment: @rickhg12hs thank you, i did it and for some reason it throws error: `radius must be a non-negative number`. You can try it here: 

[link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cSS4wo2hwle)

Comment: That's annoying.  It seems the radius value needs to be a constant, not something calculated by the server or even another field value in the document.

Answer (score 0):

The example on mongoplayground won't work because the `$geoWithin` query operator doesn't interpret `$location.raidus` as the value of the document but as the string `$location.raidus`. That's why it keeps saying `query failed: (BadValue) radius must be a non-negative number` (not because it's a negative number but because it a string so not a number at all).

That been said, you should try using the `$geoNear` aggregation operator : https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$geoNear": {
      "near": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -103.83176,
          20.88196
        ]
      },
      "distanceField": "exactDistance"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $lte: [
          "$exactDistance",
          "$location.radius"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

It won't work on mongoplayground because it needs a 2d sphere index, but might work for your project.